# Add the email address for multiple security groups from a csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv file with a list of groups with their email addresses. I need add these email addresses to the mail attribut security group in AD (no exchange). In the csv the first column is labeled group (###.testgroup) second column is labeled mail (###.testgroup@domain.com).

When I run this script

```
Import-CSV -path 'C:\Temp\test.csv' | ForEach-Object {Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.group -Replace @{mail="$_.mail"}}
```

It returns the following instead of the actual email address the mail field.

@{group=###.testgroup; mail=domain.com}.mail

Comment: -Replace @{mail="$_.mail"}} --> -Replace @{mail="$($_.mail)"}} or even simplier --> @{mail=$_.mail}}

Comment: I need add these email addresses to the mail attribute of multiple security groups in AD (no exchange).

Comment: `"$_.mail"` can't expand because of `".."`. Remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because of the double quotes around "$*.mail" which cast your object "$*" to a string and then add litterally ".mail" at the end of the string.
To bypass this behaviour, (for example when you want to use write-host) you can use this :

```
"$($_.mail)"
```

Or in your case, you can simply remove the quotes which gives:

```
Import-CSV -path 'C:\Temp\test.csv' | ForEach-Object {Set-ADGroup -Identity $_.group -Replace @{mail=$_.mail}}
```

Comment: That was it. Works perfectly. Thanks so much.